# Pre-Calculus Self learning resources, ENG/FRE

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, self-learning

Hello and a pleasant day to all!

For a couple of months, I've been studying math on my own accord, with a mild goal of mastering every pre-calculus topic by the end of summer. Tomorrow would mark the end to my Trigonometry course, which I assume would be the last of the topics I'd need before taking pre-calculus. The problem is, however, in regard to the speed at which I am passing through topics, I am not sure if I am being exposed enough to topics to fully comprehend them, and am also not sure if i am 100% not missing out on any important subjects without notice.

I've started from 8th grade basics and in 2 months time finished Algebra I&II, Geometry, Trigonometry. The reason why I am not sure if i am being exposed to everything I need is mainly because i study from one source, Khan Academy , and then delve over parts i don't understand.

Trigonometry, for instance , took less than 4 days till it's over. Finishing a unit-a-day I went through not knowing what a Sin or Cosine was to solving what I'd say pretty hairy problems in the span of less than a week.

I genuinely don't want for this to come as if it's bragging, as I am really concerned at the end of the day I would forget all this when I need them for later and all my studies would go to waste.

As it is summer, I can study up to 7-10 hours a day comfortably so time isn't a constraint, with that what are some good sources in either English or French that I can study through great extend everything I may need to know before getting ready for calculus?

(I would also **greatly** appreciate if you there were any free resources where I can solve human-made problems for any of the topics listed, or any other general tips that you think would be of importance studying high-school math.)

Comment: There's an OpenStax Precalculus text. However, please allow for time for these topics to sit with you. No need of forgetting topics, because you can always go back and look them up later after first exposures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good book to learn all of precalculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322997/what-is-a-good-book-to-learn-all-of-precalculus)